# Google Maps Api: always get the province name in short mode

Tags: javascript, api, maps

sorry for my bad english.
I have used api from google maps.
There is a way to the province name always be in short mode?

like that: province name = "Acre" short name = "AC".

tks!

my code:

```
var customStyled = [
        {
            featureType: "all",
            elementType: "labels",
            stylers: [
                { visibility: "off" }
            ]
        },
        {
            featureType: "administrative.province",
            elementType: "labels",
            stylers: [
                {
                    visibility: "on"
                }
            ]
        },
    ];

    function initMap(data) {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
            //center: new google.maps.LatLng(-13.6632305, -69.6410913),//Brasil
            zoom: 4.3,
            minZoom: 3,
            maxZoom: 7,
            streetViewControl: false,

            center: BRASIL,
            restriction: {
                latLngBounds: BRASIL_BOUNDS,
                strictBounds: false,
            },
           
            stylers: {
                color: "#7c0a02",
                visibility: "off",
            },
            
        });
        map.data.setStyle({
            fillColor: "red",
            strokeWeight: 1
        });
        map.set('styles', customStyled);
```